# Can I create a global dataset in a function

Tags: r, assign

To improve speed i create some general global data set that are always available. From time to time they need to be updated.

I am trying to do this in a function that i will call when the dataset needs to be updated.

Is there any way you can create a global dataset in a function in R? I am aware of the assign function, but I cannot get the function to work for a dataframe, only a variable.

How do i do that?

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)

z <- function ()  x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

now when i run z(), it should update x to (1...10)

Comment: Try with `<<-` operator

Comment: It’s possible but **strongly discouraged**. Functions that modify global scope are an anti-pattern. Instead, you need to change the data access logic of your code to make this unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

> I am aware of the assign function, but I cannot get the function to work for a dataframe, only a variable.

Odd: `assign` works the same way for all types of objects, regardless of their type:

```
assign('name', object, environment)
```

In your case, this would be:

```
assign('x', your_df, globalenv())
```

— But as mentioned in a comment, **modifying objects outside the function’s scope is a very bad idea** (there are very few exceptions). The *correct* way for your function to work is to *return* the modified/created object from the function.

To use your example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)

z <- function () c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

# Usage:

x <- z()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `<<-` operator for assigning variables globally

```
z <- function ()  x <<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
z()
x
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```